# why when i try to create a .json file i dont have acess

Tags: windows, command-prompt

C:\Users\matti\subreme>type nul> mainfest.json
Access is denied.

C:\Users\matti\subreme>echo.> mainfest.json
Access is denied.

am i doing somthing wrong here?

Comment: Run `dir /a C:\Users\matti\subreme` to check whether the file already exists and maybe is flagged as hidden, system, or readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the directory/folder `C:\Users\matti\subreme` was created by another user?

try running the same command with `CMD - Run as administrator`  and see if you still have a problem.